# How can I add a field to Azure DevOps bug/task? It is disabled for me

Tags: configuration, azure-devops

I created organization and am the administrator - but I can't add a field to a bug or task as per documentation - tried it in all - agile, scrum, and CMMI. The documentation does not explain why something is disabled - why is this?? How can I add a field to bug/task?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an [inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#create-an-inherited-process) first, then edit that process.

[image]